# Regular expression for finding image src in content using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
eg: "Brown fox image  <img src="http://imageurl.com/image.png" alt="Some Text"> some text"
```

How to get "src" value using regular expressions.

Answer:

```
getImage(content) {
    var myRegexp = new RegExp(/<img.*?src="(.*?)"/);
    var match = myRegexp.exec(content);
    if (match)
      return match[1];
  }
```

Comment: Don't. Parse the string to DOM elements and access the `src` property of the `img` element.

Comment: what is the origin of that string? Text content or  a part of javascript code?

Comment: Someone post that question, you know the one

Comment: @OlivierGrech http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/218196